# WooCommerce Bookings Custom Email Template for Non Admin Users

Tags: php, wordpress, email, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I develop a site something close to airbnb, where customers can make a reservation on the accommodations using the WooCommerce Bookings plug-in. When booking a reservation, a confirmation of availability is being checked by the admins, once the administrator has confirmed availability, I would like to use a custom email template that sends an email to the owner of the accommodation.

The owner's email associated with the accommodation is stored on each individual accommodation as a custom field.

What I want to accomplish is the ability to create an custom email template that goes out to the right owner when the accommodation is verified by admin.

Question: How do I create my own template and what hook do I use?

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/custom-email-templates/ , or if you want it custom then I can give you steps

Comment: If you could point me the right way to do it custom I would be happy, since everything is stored correctly I would just want the right way to create an own template and try to hook on to some WooCommerce hook when the booking is confirmed, in addition to this the email to the owner of the accommodation is in a custom field and needs to be the recipient of the email.